# Email with attachment working on gmail but not on Outlook or my mailserver

Tags: php, email, outlook, email-attachments

I already checked the similar questions on site but didn't find anything. I am sending an attachment with the email which generates on the form submission. It is working great on Gmail but on Outlook or on my office mailserver, the email is coming with empty attachment. To be precise the attachment is coming without any data in it.

Here is my code:

```
$row = $this->model_catalog_bulk_order_reset->getresetinfotest($orderid)->rows;
$filename= $orderid;
$filename='excel/'.$filename.'.csv';
$fp=fopen($filename,"w");
$seperator="";

foreach($row as $name =>$value)

{
    if($name==0){

        $seperator="";

        $comma="";
        foreach($value as $name =>$value)

        {

        $seperator.=$comma.''.str_replace('','""',$name);
        $comma=",";

        }

        $seperator.="\n";
        fputs($fp,$seperator);
    }


}

foreach($row as $name =>$value)

{
    $seperator="";

    $comma="";
    foreach($value as $name =>$value)
    {
        $newValue = explode('-',$value);

        $count = count($newValue);

        if($count > 1){

            $value = $newValue[0]." to ".$newValue[1];
        }else{
            $value = $newValue[0];
        }


        $seperator.=$comma.''.str_replace('','""',$value);
        $comma=",";

    }

    $seperator.="\n";
    fputs($fp,"'".$seperator);

}

fclose($fp);
$filename= $orderid;
$my_file = $filename.'.csv';
$filename = $filename.'.csv';
$path = "excel/";


$from_name = "XYZ";

$from_mail = $this->config->get('config_email');

$mailto = $customer_record['email'].",".$this->config->get('config_email');

$subject = "Bulk order.";

$body = "Hi,\r\n Please find the attachment?";

$replyto=$this->config->get('config_email');
$file = $path.$my_file;
    $file_size = filesize($file);


$handle = fopen($file, "r");

$content = fread($handle, $file_size);

fclose($handle);

$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$name = basename($file);

$eol = PHP_EOL;

 $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">".$eol;

$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto.$eol;

$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"";


$message = "--".$uid.$eol;

$message .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol;

$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;

$message .= $body.$eol;
$message .= "--".$uid.$eol;

$message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 

$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;

$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;

$message .= $content.$eol;

$message .= "--".$uid."--";

mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well phpMailer fixed it.

```
    $subject = "Bulk Order";
    $message = "Hello!";

    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
    $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
    $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
    $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

    $mail->setTo($customer_record['email']);
    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_name'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    $mail->setText($message);
    $mail->addAttachment($filename);
    $mail->send();
```